# calcular suma por mes

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un problema con esta consulta, necesito que se sumen los saldo en total por mes y tipo de moneda no se agrupan con un where aplicando esta forma 01 <= MM <= 12 y aun así nada , cual seria la solucion para este problema necesito su ayuda por favor y gracias totales.

```
  select 
   convert(varchar,right('0000'+convert(varchar,contd.ejercicio),4))+''+
   convert(varchar,right('00'+convert(varchar,contd.periodo),2))+''+
   convert(varchar,right('00'+Convert(varchar,Datepart(Day, 
   contd.FechaContable)),2))as Periodo,contd.Cuenta,
   (case contd.cuenta
            when '10166' then '99'  --C.Chica Boutique Chanel
            when '10167' then '99'  --C.Chica Swarovski Jockey Plaza
            when '10168' then '99'  --C.Chica Vulcano
            when '10169' then '99'  --C.Chica Swarovski RP Salaverry
            when '10170' then '99'  --C.Chica Real Plaza Salaverry
            when '10416' then '2'   --Banco de Credito Dolares
            else '_'
            end) as Codigo,
            isnull(ctadinero.NumeroCta,0)as Nrocuenta,
            (Case ctadinero.Moneda
                     WHEN 'Soles' then 'PEN'
                    WHEN 'Dolares' then 'USD'
                    WHEN 'Euros' then 'EUR'
                    ELSE 'PEN' END) as Moneda, 
             sum(case when isnull(contd.debe,0) > isnull(contd.haber,0)  
   then (isnull(contd.debe,0) - isnull(contd.haber,0)) else 0 end) 
  SaldoDeudor,
             sum(case when isnull(contd.haber,0) > isnull(contd.debe,0)  
  then (isnull(contd.haber,0) - isnull(contd.debe,0)) else 0 end) 
 SaldoAcreedor,
             '1' as Estado
 from contd  (nolock)
 left outer join cont on contd.id=cont.id 
 left outer join ctadinero (nolock) on ctadinero.cuenta = contd.cuenta
 WHERE Contd.Cuenta like '10%'
             and contd.ejercicio = '2018'
             and cont.estatus='CONCLUIDO' 
 group by contd.ejercicio, contd.periodo, contd.FechaContable, cont.id, 
 ctadinero.NumeroCta, ctadinero.Moneda, contd.Cuenta
 ORDER BY contd.FechaContable, Codigo desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si buscas agrupar por moneda y mes, solo debieras agrupar únicamente por estas columnas.

Comment: en teoría a si debería de ser pero al tener join cambia el tema, por que estas concatenando otras tablas ,si me dejo entender.

Comment: El join no tiene nada que ver con el group. Uno agrupa por las columnas que va a mostrar, y vos estas agrupando por cualquier cosa. No entiendo como esta consulta no tira error, ya que esas columnas no estan en el select.

Comment: Para resolver lo que preguntas deberías dejar en el `select` y en el `group by` únicamente `convert(varchar,right('00'+convert(varchar,contd.periodo),2))` y el `case` de `ctadinero.Moneda` y en el `select` los dos `sum()`.

Comment: Seria ideal si puedes entregar un ejemplo del resultado esperado, se me ocurren varias formas de realizar lo que indicas, pero seria en base a supuestos.

Comment: seria que se sumen todas las cuentas
para agrupar y dar un resultado, teniendo en cuenta el numero cta bancario.
no se si me dejo entender